# calculate HD resolutions for an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image with height=75pixels and width=75pixels (75x75).

I want to calculate what the resolution for this image would be in different resolutions  [480p (640x480), 720p (1280x720), and 1080p (1920x1080)] while still keeping the image's original aspect ratio.

For example, I know if I keep multiplying by 2 that eventually I will reach a number for each resolution like so:

```
75x75     * 2 = 144x144
144x144   * 2 = 288x288
288x288   * 2 = 576x576
576x576   * 2 = 1152x1152  (This resolution would be just over 480p)
1152x1152 * 2 = 2304x2304  (This resolution would be over 720/1080p)
```

How can I calculate different resolutions for an image while keeping the original aspect ratio?

Comment: The original aspect ratio is 1:1 - whereas the resolutions we commonly use for viewing are in 16:9...

Comment: Yes but I dont want to stretch my original image or add padding around it

Comment: So will you crop the image? You will need to do something to make the image fit into 16:9

Comment: i dont want to crop the image, and i udnerstand it wont be exactly 1920x1080, im just trying to find the minimum resolution based on my img to be at least 1920x1080